# Crossbar ImportError: cannot import name parseWsUrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, crossbar

- Created virtual environment: `virtualenv my_test`
- Installed crossbar: `source bin/activate && pip install crossbar`
- Following are the packages:

  Jinja2==2.8
  MarkupSafe==0.23
  PyNaCl==1.0.1
  PyTrie==0.2
  PyYAML==3.11
  Pygments==2.1.3
  Twisted==16.1.1
  argparse==1.2.1
  attrs==15.2.0
  autobahn==0.13.1
  cbor==1.0.0
  cffi==1.5.2
  click==6.6
  crossbar==0.13.0
  cryptography==1.3.1
  enum34==1.1.2
  idna==2.1
  ipaddress==1.0.16
  lmdb==0.89
  mistune==0.7.2
  msgpack-python==0.4.7
  netaddr==0.7.18
  psutil==4.1.0
  pyOpenSSL==16.0.0
  pyasn1==0.1.9
  pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
  pycparser==2.14
  pyinotify==0.9.6
  requests==2.9.1
  sdnotify==0.3.0
  service-identity==16.0.0
  setproctitle==1.1.9
  shutilwhich==1.1.0
  six==1.10.0
  treq==15.1.0
  txaio==2.3.1
  ujson==1.35
  wsaccel==0.6.2
  wsgiref==0.1.2
  zope.interface==4.1.3
- Generated a hello template using the command: crossbar init --template hello:python --appdir hello
- Tried to run cross bar`cd hello; crossbar start`

got error:

```
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973] Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/bin/crossbar", line 9, in <module>
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     load_entry_point('crossbar==0.13.0', 'console_scripts', 'crossbar')()
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/controller/cli.py", line 992, in run
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     options.func(options, reactor=reactor)
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/controller/cli.py", line 560, in run_command_start
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     from crossbar.controller.node import maybe_generate_key
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/controller/node.py", line 52, in <module>
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     from crossbar.worker.router import RouterRealm
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/worker/router.py", line 63, in <module>
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     from crossbar.worker.testee import WebSocketTesteeServerFactory, \
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/worker/testee.py", line 44, in <module>
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     from crossbar.worker.worker import NativeWorkerSession
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/worker/worker.py", line 48, in <module>
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     from crossbar.common.process import NativeProcessSession
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/common/process.py", line 67, in <module>
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     from crossbar.common import checkconfig
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]   File "/home/romaan/workspacepy/tester/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar/common/checkconfig.py", line 44, in <module>
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973]     from autobahn.websocket.protocol import parseWsUrl
2016-04-13T15:43:20+1000 [Controller   2973] ImportError: cannot import name parseWsUrl
```

Please help me fix it. I know that parseWsUrl is not present in autobahn.websocket.protocol but this error is coming from crossbar library. Hence how do I fix it? or workaround it?

Comment: maybe related: https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/pull/619

Comment: `from autobahn.websocket.util import parse_url as parseWsUrl` might be a possible workaround while this issue is sorted.